# Как сохранить документ .docx в файл при загрузке на клиент через AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob

Сервер возвращает такие данные (ответ POST запроса): [image: бракозябры, ответ сервера]

По задумке, это документ .docx и его нужно сохранить на клиенте.

(для передачи данных используется ajax, не знаю, следует ли ставить этот тег)

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть заголовки ответа сервера и код загрузки файла.

Answer (score 2):

Что то подобное делал год назад.

Основные вехи:

- получаем массив
- запихиваем его в UINT8Array
- создаем ссылку на документе
- нажимаем на нее
- не забываем удалить ссылку после нажатия

Приведенный ниже пример не будет работать из за CORS. Если поставите ссылку на документ с правильно оформленным CORS, то он будет автоматически скачиваться

```js
        // Скачиваем AJAX запросом демонстрационнфй docx файл
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("GET", "http://www.doe.mass.edu/mcas/testadmin/manual/PAM-AltSetting.docx", true);
        oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
            var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // только не oReq.responseText
            if (arrayBuffer) {
                var data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                var filename = "test.docx";
                var type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
                // Если это IE10+
                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
                else { // Другие браузеры
                    var a = document.createElement("a"),
                    url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.body.removeChild(a);
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
                    }, 0); 
                }
        }
    }
    oReq.send();
```

Comment: спасибо! К сожалению (или к счастью) изменили серверное API и решили этот вопрос по-другому. Если предоставится случай, проверю с созданием UINT8Array